# Create a playlist with Spotify iOS SDK in Swift 5

Tags: ios, swift, spotify

Question says it all. I'm trying to interact with getting/creating/editing playlists using the Spotify iOS SDK in Swift 5. I can't find any documentation about it at all and all the other Stackoverflow questions I find are a few years old or not relevant. I'm using the SPTAppRemote, but I've got a feeling that I can't interact with playlists using this class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way I found to interact with playlists and API endpoints was to use the `access_token` you receive from logging in and then sending regular API requests to the Web API with that token. It seems like the iOS SDK is more for authentication and playback while the Web API is used for manipulating playlists, searching, etc.